# Calling HTTP API endpoint in Azure Managed SQL

Tags: sql-server, sendgrid, sp-send-dbmail, azure-sql-managed-instance, msxml2.xmlhttp

I am in the process of integrating SendGrid APIs with Azure Managed SQL and I am facing the below issue.

I am required to send an email via the SendMail() API and get the response back to SQL Server.
Since I am using SQL Managed instance, I cannot use the **MSXML2.XMLHTTP** to call the APIs.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

--Code Snippet
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post',  
             '<API URL HERE >', -- API URL
             'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
Select @ResponseText  --
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Above code snip returns

> Msg 17750, Level 16, State 0, Procedure sp_OACreate, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Could not load the DLL odsole70.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
> Msg 17750, Level 16, State 0, Procedure sp_OAMethod, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Could not load the DLL odsole70.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
> Msg 17750, Level 16, State 0, Procedure sp_OAMethod, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Could not load the DLL odsole70.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
> Msg 17750, Level 16, State 0, Procedure sp_OAMethod, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Could not load the DLL odsole70.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

Is there any alternate way to achieve this task using SQL Managed Instance?

I can simply use the **sp_send_dbmail** utility, however, I cannot grab the returning MessageID from SendGrid if I use the Database Mail feature. (Or is there a way to get it?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to do this stuff from sql? I'm thinking perhaps there can be a middle layer which connects these two

Comment: @siggemannen I am about to apply this solution for an existing application that already uses dbmail functionality. I am trying to find whether there is an approach with minimal changes. If this is not possible, YES I have to go for a middle layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OLE Automation stored procedures are not supported in Managed Instance.  You can use CLR procedures, though.  There's a sample for it on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/sql-clr/Curl